# How to pass Fragment to Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

Here is my code:

```
loginButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.loginBtn);

loginButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent= new Intent(context, searchview_cardview.class);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Comment: Your question is unclear

Comment: What you want exactly?

Comment: Try this   Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), searchview_cardview.class);
startActivity(intent);

Comment: can i know that  searchview_cardview is class or fragment

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), searchview_cardview.class); startActivity(intent); I try but error(getActivity())   searchview_cardview class

Answer (score 0):

To pass data to another activity, you can use the code below:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), otherActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("Key", Value);
                startActivity(intent);
```

Then, to pass data to parent activity you should create a function in parent activity and call it like this in your fragment:

in activity:

```
  public void GoToNextStep(String title) {
   // some codes
}
```

in fragment :

```
((yourActivity) getContext()).GoToNextStep("var");
```